# eclipse errors with Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: tfs

Using the TFS anywhere plugin. On starting Eclipse there's an alleged connection error but the connection is already setup and working and I can't find anything wrong with it or integrated security.

[image]

There are InvocationTargetException errors as well per [eclipse invocationtargetexception error with TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454523/eclipse-invocationtargetexception-error-with-tfs)

Comment: i have a similar problem and after uninstalling and re-installing eclipse and TEE plug-in, everything connects and works.

Comment: @LeoBL yeah I have also just re-installed but get the error ;-)

Comment: What's the TFS  anywhere plugin? Are you just talking about Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse  plug-in? What's your detail TFS and plug-in version? Are you using Git or TFVC as your source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Customer solved this issue by point JDK from 11 to JDK 8.

---

For this kind error we would suggest you first follow this official document [Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse(Azure DevOps Services and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=azure-devops) to make sure you have installed “Team Explorer Everywhere” in eclipse properly.

This may related you are lacking some component during installation. Or your eclipse version is too new. Give a try with a eclipse version which released in 2018.

Then you could just follow this document [Connect to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-eclipse?view=azure-devops#connect-to-azure-devops-services) to use Team Explorer Everywhere and also check if you have connected to TFS with the corresponding steps.